# Fetch data using Prisma in Sveltekit

Tags: svelte, prisma, sveltekit

I'm learning Sveltekit and trying to figure out how to fetch data from my postgresql database via Prisma (prisma.casino.findMany()). I'm aware I might be quite far off in my code and would appreciate some help on the way.

Right now I am just receiving an:

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
on the: "{#each casinos as casino (casino.id)}" line in the index.svelte file.

How do I correctly fetch data in Sveltekit using prisma?

Please see my files below:

**components/Casino/_api**

```
import type { Locals } from '$lib/types';
import PrismaClient from '$lib/prisma';
import type { RequestEvent } from '@sveltejs/kit';
import type internal from 'stream';
const prisma = new PrismaClient();

export type Casino = {
    id: string;
    name: string;
};

export async function api(event: RequestEvent, resource: string, data?: Casino) {
    let body = {};
    let status = 500;
    switch (event.request.method.toUpperCase()) {
        case 'GET':
            body = await prisma.casino.findMany();
            status = 200;
            break;
    }

    if (
        event.request.method !== 'GET' &&
        event.request.headers.get('accept') !== 'application/json'
    ) {
        return {
            status: 303,
            headers: {
                location: '/'
            }
        };
    }

    return {
        status,
        body
    };
}
```

**components/Casino/index.json.ts**

```
import type { RequestHandler } from '@sveltejs/kit';
import { api } from './_api';

// GET /todos.json
export const get: RequestHandler = async (request) => {
    // request.locals.userid comes from src/hooks.js
    const response = await api(request, `casinos/`);

    if (response.status === 404) {
        // user hasn't created a todo list.
        // start with an empty array
        return { body: [] };
    }

    return response;
};
```

**components/Casino/index.svelte**

```
<script context="module" lang="ts">
    import type { Load } from '@sveltejs/kit';
    // see https://kit.svelte.dev/docs#loading
    export const load: Load = async ({ fetch }) => {
        const res = await fetch('/casinos');
        if (res.ok) {
            const casinos = await res.json();
            return {
                props: { casinos }
            };
        }
        const { message } = await res.json();
        return {
            error: new Error(message)
        };
        console.log(res);
    };
</script>

<script lang="ts">
    import type { Casino } from './_api';
    export let casinos: Casino[];
</script>

<section>
    {#each casinos as casino (casino.id)}
        <p>{ casino.name } </p>
    {/each}
</section>
```

Comment: As the error message the `casinos` is undefined. You may need initialize that variable with an empty array or you can use nullish coalescing operator in each block like `{#each (casinos ?? []) as ...}`.

Comment: Have you tested your `/casinos` API route in isolation, with a tool like Postman or Insomnia? Can you show us the relevant files in your `src/routes` subtree?